# Syntax of "segment at" in assembly language

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm, memory-segmentation

```
newsegm segment at 0B800h
...
newsegm ends
```

Can you describe what does it mean? I have another segment with the address 0B800h?
 The reason why I ask is:
 I have a code with these strings

```
lea DX, message 
message DB "Hello, World!",'$'  
VIDEO DD 0B800h:072Eh
```

The teacher highlighted `0B800h:072Eh` and `message`and said to write an expression using the vidsegm segment name. I don't know what does he want and what to do

Answer (score 4):

**Essential part:**
You can refer to the char at the position in the video segment with the handle `newsegm` at the position `newsegm:072Eh`.

**Further explanation:**
The address `0B800` hexadecimal is the starting address of the video segment for text mode. The directive

```
newsegm segment at 0B800h
...
newsegm ends
```

defines a shortcut for this segment address.
In this `0B800` video segment, each char on the display consists of two bytes: the color code and the char code. So the address in your second code sample, `0B800h:072Eh`, points to the

> 072Eh/2 = 919d   ; two bytes per char
>   919d/80d = 11d   ; line number
>   919d%80d = 39d   ; column number

It points to the char at position line 11, column 39 (starting with 0).

Comment: That very last sentence with `newsegm:072Eh` should at least be bolded, and using code-formatting for the expression.  Or better, should be at the top of the answer *followed by* the explanation.  AFAICT, that's what the question is really looking for as an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thank you for your useful suggestions.